# setSpinnersShown and setCalendarViewShown on DatePicker deprecated in API level 24

Tags: android, mobile, datepicker, datepickerdialog

I tried to switch to calendar to spinner mode in **DatePicker** by changing `setSpinnersShown` and `setCalendarViewShown` value programmatically, but in API 24, Android Studio shows the `deprecated` warning.

What is the alternative ways for me to set my DatePicker from calendar to spinner mode programmatically without set values on XML in API 24. Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?  It seems strange that a method was deprecated in such a way that it no longer seems possible to achieve this functionality.

Comment: I still don't find any answers to this question ...

Answer (score 0):

Add the attribute calendarViewShown and set it to false in xml:

```
<DatePicker
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/date_field"
android:calendarViewShown="false"/>
```

Comment: Thanks but the DatePicker I created is on the java code, not in xml.

Comment: @Michael : there is no need for xml to create a DatePIcker dialog unless you are creating a custom date picker.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when trying to generate a Jetpack Compose wrapper where I've created a date picker in wheel style. Fixed it like this (xml needed in styles.xml but no layout files needed):

In styles.xml

```
    <style name="SpinnerMode" parent="android:Widget.Material.DatePicker">
        <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>
        <item name="android:calendarViewShown">false</item>
    </style>

    <style name="datepicker_dark">
        <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/SpinnerMode</item>
        <!-- Text color -->
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">...</item>
    </style>
```

And instantiate the Picker like this:

```
val customContext = androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.datepicker_dark)

DatePicker(customContext).apply {
    this.updateDate(2023, 6, 1)
    // ...
}
```